# How to convert a linear dicarboxylate species to the dimethyl ester?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I was wondering about the *ozonolysis* of *cyclohexane* and further treatment with $\ce{H2O2}$. I understand that the product to this reaction is *hexanedioic acid*.

How could we substitute the $\ce{-H}$ on each carboxylic group to a methyl, as in the following structure:

[image]

I am pretty sure it would be by adding two moles of *methanol* (Fischer esterification). Is this procedure correct?

Comment: I would try $\ce{NaOH}$ and then $\ce{MeI}$. And in one step but more dangerous you can prepare in a solution of $\ce{CH2N2}$.

Comment: I think I would prefer sodium hydride to sodium hydroxide. Otherwise, agree with everything else.

Comment: Oh, I see. But I thought Williamson synthesis was used for synthesising ethers from alcohols?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

- Your acid-catalyzed *Fisher* esterification is one of them. The downside is that water, which is liberated in the reaction, has a higher boiling point than methanol. You can't just destill it off to drive the reaction to completion.
- *Zhe* and  *Hexacoordinate-C* mentioned diazomethane and methyl iodide which might work well. You might want to make sure that your DNA does not get methylated.
- The *Steglich* esterification, using dicyclohexylcarbodiimide (DCC) and N,N'-dimethylaminopyridine (DMAP) might be an alternative to the *Fisher* esterifiction.
- You might want to try something different, using dimethyl carbonate as a non-cancerogenic alkylation reagent. The procedure is described in [*Green Chemistry Letters and Reviews*, **2013**, *61*, 89-93](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/17518253.2012.706647) and uses potassium carbonate as a base, dimethyl carbonate as a reagent (and solvent), and tetrabutylammonium chloride as a catalyst.